# Out of Date PHP code? Cannot get CMS to function

Tags: php, sql

The CMS displays data but is non responsive or editable. The code is old from 2005.

Someone suggested some of the syntax has been deprecated and no longer works.
I'm such a non-coder, my searching has revealed nothing I have been reading the basics on Tizag and SQL syntax but I am not catching it.  Can someone look at this code and tell me if it is indeed deprecated.  I've tried to enter this question a couple of time but keep going into the similar questions link to look for clues.

```
if($signinsubmit){
    $sqlsignin = "SELECT * FROM cms_users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
    $resultsignin = mysql_query($sqlsignin);
    $signinrow=mysql_fetch_array($resultsignin);

    if($signinrow[password]==$pass && mysql_num_rows($resultsignin)!=0){
        include_once 'assets/includes/session.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of PHP ? `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Might be you had register_globals() on? See you're using likely `$_POST` values as if the directive were active

Comment: `$signinrow[password]` should be `$signinrow["password"]`

Comment: thank you Leknath.  I am not sure how to tell which version.

Comment: *"they"* were referring specifically to the `mysql_*` family of functions.  PHP offers (and has done for quite a while now) a variety of [interfaces and abstraction layers](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) which among other things - provide tools to better optimise and secure (when used correctly) your application.

Comment: Note that "deprecated" doesn't mean "no longer works", it means "is no longer supported, and will stop working soon". You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to a more modern set of MySQL functions (MySQLi or PDO), but those ones should run fine under PHP 5.5. If the code is relying on register_globals, however, that was deprecated a long time ago, and has now been completely removed: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Re "I am not sure how to tell which version." - leknath already gave you [the command to find out info on your current environment](http://php.net/phpinfo), just put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a (**temporary**) PHP file and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered my question.  I feel bad for wasting all your time.  I've surpassed my own incompetence.  I realized after posting and reading the kind responses that I'm not there yet. Not only did I not really understand my question but the answers even less.  I was in over my head.  I am very grateful for the responses.  You people are awesome! I think I need to learn the basics before I bother you all again.